# Webpack 5 Module federation micro-frontend and react-redux is not working

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, webpack-5, webpack-module-federation

Trying to migrate an existing react + redux application to micro frontend.

```
Container (Parent App) - localhost:8080
ReactReduxApp (Child App - 1) - localhost:8081
ReactApp (Child App - 2) - localhost:8082
```

The independent application can run with react-redux in its PORT.
When accessing it as a child application inside a container application, Container application is not loading and throwing below ERROR

```
Error: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(IndexPage)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or pass a custom React context provider to <Provider> and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(IndexPage) in connect options.
```

Without **ReactReduxApp(Child1)** my **Container(Parent)** app is running fine with **ReactApp(Child2)**

Answer (score 8):

## Solution

Use `singleton: true` for every shared library that uses React Context:

```js
// webpack.config.js

// import package.json to get packages' versions
const deps = require('./package.json').dependencies

module.exports = {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: 'main',
      filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
      remotes: {
        // your remotes config
      },
      shared: {
        react: {
          singleton: true,
          version: deps['react']
        },
        'react-dom': {
          singleton: true,
          version: deps['react-dom']
        },
        'react-router-dom': {
          singleton: true,
          version: deps['react-router-dom']
        },
        'react-redux': {
          singleton: true,
          version: deps['react-router-dom']
        }
      },
    }),
    // other plugins
  ]
```

Use this setting in all of your federated modules.

### Solution for custom context

If your app has a custom context there is a similar solution. Take a look at the [example](https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation-examples/blob/f196c14fb91476152e0c3029e79a1758c7399ffb/shared-routing/shell/webpack.config.js#L77) in the module-federation-examples monorepo.

## Explanation

[Such errors arise when you have two copies of React Context in your apps](https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation-examples/issues/730#issuecomment-815331139). Redux, React Router, Material UI, and other libraries use Context API inside their providers. So when you have, for example, Redux imported in both of your WP5 federated modules, every module (or app) has its own copy of Redux, even if it is the same version of it.

## Workaround

If for some reason you can't have singleton module, there is a workaround: pass your Redux store to the remote app's props and wrap it with another Provider like so:

```js
// in your remote app:
const RemoteAppWrapper = ({ store }) => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <RemoteApp />
    </Provider>
  );
};

// and then in your host app:
<RemoteApp store={store} />
```

There is an app with a complete example in the official module-federation-examples monorepo where this approach is used: https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation-examples/tree/master/redux-reducer-injection

Comment: This works for most packages, but some, like apollo/client, require react in such a way that a warning is given at compile time about not being able to find React. Interestingly, the code compiles and runs just fine. Wondering if you've come across something like that and how you resolved it.

Comment: the option with singleton looks like the only correct, but it doesn't work with react-redux and redux/toolkit (for some reason, still looking for the issue), as for the RemoteAppWrapper it breaks the Router system of the app hard, so I can't use any of container routes ((

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should try this [redux-micro-frontend](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-micro-frontend) instead of origin redux